# Is max entropy invariant under choice of base?

Tags: information-theory

Suppose I have a set of probability mass functions $S_1,\dots,S_n$ and I find that $S_j$ has the greatest entropy using the traditional formula for entropy using $\sum_{i\in S}-p_i \log_2(p_i)$.

In this case we're using a base of 2. Is it guaranteed that if instead I used any other base greater than 1 that I would find that $S_j$ has the greatest entropy?

Seems like this would be a needed property in information theory, otherwise it seems like it would be hard to argue we're interested in dividing the space into halves instead of thirds or fifths etc...

Comment: It's just a unit conversion.

Comment: Oh, thanks. $\log_b (x) = \log (x) / \log (b)$. Sorry I didn't figure that out before asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

The maxima are the same, because entropy in one base is a constant multiple of the entropy in another. It's a unit conversion—for example, base $2$ measures entropy in bits, and base $e$ measures entropy in nats.

As OP notes, this is because $\log_b(x) = \log(x) / \log(b)$.